# How to check Proxy setting values in android TV?

Tags: android, proxy, android-tv

I have a task to set the Proxy in android TV without using android API. so i am using the below command

```
adb shell settings put global http_proxy <host name>:<port>
```

command is executing properly but i want to see the values which i passed. 
how can i check the values (not using java api) which i passed via this command ?.
is there any command or is there any place in TV i can check the hostname and values ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check proxy settings in AndroidTV settings menu.

`AndroidTV Home > Settings > Network & Internet > {Connected network} > Proxy settings`